# Statistical modeling resources for a beginner

Tags: probability, modeling

I already had some courses in statistics and probability.

I would like to learn about **statistical modeling**. I was looking for resources for a beginner to start with and show me some examples how to use probability and statistical concepts step by step using statistics tools.

Would you please share your experience with me and introduce some resources to start with?

Comment: Any particular sort of models?

Comment: Let's say I have a data and I think It fits Poisson Distribution. How should I proceed? how can test whether this is the proper model, ...basically I think first of all I should learn from some examples (applications) how people apply it on the data and what the steps are. But I need some suggestions what would be the proper way of starting